# Configure Travis CI for MySQL on Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

I'm trying to configure Travis CI build for my Ruby on Rails project on GitHub, however the MySQL configuration is not working. What is wrong with my config?

.travis.yml

```
language: ruby
before_script:
  - mysql -e 'create database simple_cms_test;'
rvm:
  - 2.1
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development
  username: simple_cms
  password: xpto


test:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_test
  username: root
```

Travis CI gives access denied for the database configuration.
"Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

The repository is https://github.com/julianonunes/simple_cms

Comment: Didn't know they have this tool, but it gives me "Hooray, your .travis.yml seems to be solid!"

Comment: Have you tried adding the MySQL example configuration for your database.yml file? http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#config-database.yml-Example

Comment: Their sample is like mine, only the database name is different.

Comment: In your database.yml file, add the fields in the section marked test with what is shown in the link I sent. For example, username should be ```travis```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `database.yml` file should include the following under `test`:

```
test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql12
  database: simple_cms_test
  username: travis
  encoding: utf8
```

As seen in the documentation: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#config-database.yml-Example

Comment: To be more specific the problem was just the username. Despite the docs mention root username, I had to use travis as the username. Thanks.